# Media folder defaulting to Orchard.Web

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Right now when I upload media it defaults to saving to the media folder within Orchard.Web but then when the image is displayed the file path is referencing the regular Orchard folder. How do I go about changing this?

I'm using VisualStudio for a shared team project if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: How do you display the image?

Comment: It's just included in a blog post, "insert media" in the editor

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Which Orchard version? Which editor? (probably the default TinyMCE?)

Comment: What does "the regular Orchard folder" mean?

Comment: I'm referencing the folder titled "Orchard" thinking that that's where OrchardLocal references. I guess I'm a little confused, how does OrchardLocal know where to reference the Media folder?

Comment: I realized that the image is referencing outside of my directory I set up for my repository, how would I go about changing that? @BertrandLeRoy

Comment: The root of the web site is Orchard.Web.

Comment: Right, so when I upload an image it is going to the Media folder within Orchard.Web but then when it comes to displaying the image it is broken. I'm not sure where the root folder is pointing and am unsure of how to change that.